# Angular Material Paginator Scrolls to Top by default

Tags: angular, angular-material, paginator

In Angular and Material 15, I used mat-paginator in cards view not table when moving next and previous actions it scroll to top by default.

```
  <mat-paginator
    *ngIf="dataSource.length > 0"
    [length]="dataSource.length - 1"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
    (page)="onPaginateChange()">
  </mat-paginator>
```

I used to stopPropagation on click but it didn't work. How I can stop it?